# NX/known-kanji-only words match site or app?

Tags: discussion, kanji

I wish to make a deck in anki or play around with certain vocabulary, but I want to separate it from new kanji learning.

So the idea is to take for example N5 kanji, and make a list of matches, i.e. 一日, it's N5 only, and it goes on.

If it works I might later mix the levels and etc, as I study them, the question is:

Do I have to make the gathering all by myself or do anyone know such tool that may do it for me?

Comment: This is off-topic.  Please check our [resources list](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756), or post this on [meta](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tags.

You could select all the items in the current learning process and apply a tag such as N5 (you can apply tags to all items at once by using Ctrl+A and typing the tag). Whenever you add new items, tag the items with a new tag such as N4. You can then easily make separate decks or custom filter decks by simply selecting all items with a specific tag and moving them to a designated deck. You might want to have separate decks for each JLPT level, which you can merge at a later date when you pass that JLPT level.

Comment: wow I'm actually doing something like that :-) ty

Comment: I recommend checking out the Anki discussion forum for any questions you have https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions